# MS Word dictation has weird input box

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, voice-command

Tonight I set up voice dictation (Windows built in) on my laptop and my wife's laptop.  We both have Windows 8 with Office 2013.  When I launch word and begin dictating it acts just like it normally would.  On my wife's, however, she gets a weird little input box with two buttens, "insert" and "cancel".  What is causing this and how can I make it go away?

Answer (score 3):

Just found the problem.  Right click on the speech recognition window/icon, click options, uncheck "Enable Dictation Scratchpad".

Not sure why ours were different since mine had it checked too, but unchecking it fixed hers.